# "Sandwich theorem" for eigenvalues of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am looking for a reference for the following result for symmetric matrices

> Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be symmetric with eigenvalues
>   $\lambda_n \leq\ldots\leq\lambda_1,\, M\subset \lbrace 1 \ldots n\rbrace,\, |M|=n-1$  Now let $B\in\mathbb R^{n-1\times n-1},\, B=A(M)$ be the matrix $A$ without the $i$th row and column, where
>   $i\notin M$
>
> For the eigenvalues $\mu_{n-1} \leq \ldots \leq\mu_1$ of $B$ it holds
>
> $$\lambda_n\leq \mu_{n-1}\leq \lambda_{n-1}\leq\ldots\leq\mu_1\leq\lambda_1 $$

Does anyone know who has proved this first? And maybe a link to the original paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an application of [Courat-Fischer Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem) (or Min-Max Theorem),  and [here](http://www.aqalmoun.com/upload/concours/CNC/2004m2.pdf) there is a problem on this subject with it's [answer](http://alkendy.x10.mx/telechargements/2004C2.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

i have heard the name "Cauchy interlacing theorem" (as well as "Cauchy's interlace theorem" or  "Interlacing eigenvalues theorem for bordered matrices")Infor that theorem. that could be a hint that cauchy did it first or was among the first. 
sorry i have no idea where to find an original paper of that, but i hope my post helps anyways.