# Eigenvalues of matrix based on submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If I have the eigenvalues of matrix A, is there anything I can say about the eigenvalues of the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}+w&A_{12}&A_{13}&x\\A_{21}&A_{22}&A_{23}&0\\A_{31}&A_{32}&A_{33}&0\\y&0&0&z\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Is A symmetric ?

Comment: No, I think the only special property is that its eigenvalues are always positive

Comment: then I doubt that there is a general result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The study can be split into two tractable cases

- if $w=0$: you are in the case of "matrix bordering". In this case, see the Cauchy interlacing theorem (["Sandwich theorem" for eigenvalues of symmetric matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/902249)) which assumes the symmetry of the matrix.
- if $w > 0$, you can write the new matrix as the following sum, the second matrix being a **rank-one matrix**:

$$\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}&A_{13}&0\\A_{21}&A_{22}&A_{23}&0\\A_{31}&A_{32}&A_{33}&0\\0&0&0&(z-\dfrac{xy}{w})\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}w&0&0&x\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\y&0&0&\dfrac{xy}{w}\end{bmatrix}$$

Explanation : the 2nd matrix is a rank one matrix because it has the form:

$$\tag{*} \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{w}\\0\\0\\ \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{w}}\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{w}&0&0&\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{w}}\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, you can apply a theorem on the determinant of a matrix updated by the addition of a rank one matrix ([Determinant of rank-one perturbations of (invertible) matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/219731)), not by taking the numerical determinant but the determinant giving the characteristic polynomial.

Remark: We have assumed $w>0$. If $w<0$, replace every $\sqrt{w}$ by $\sqrt{-w}$, and take the opposite of the column vector in (*).

Comment: In the case $w>0$, how exactly are the eigenvalues determined? Using the relation $\det(X + \mathbf{c}\mathbf{d}^T) = \det(X)(1 + \mathbf{d}^T X^{-1}\mathbf{c})$ and replacing $X$ with $X-\lambda I$ results in a characteristic polynomial involving finding $(X-\lambda I)^{-1}$

Comment: Have a look at the recent article "The_bounds_of_the_eigenvalues_for_rank-one_modification_of_Hermitian_matrix" by Guanghui_Cheng that you will find on Researchgate (you have to assume that $x=y$, i.e., the new matrix is still symmetrical.